# Why does torque produce a force on the axis of rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque

If a door is rotated about its fixed axis in (outer) space, a force parallel to the door on the hinges will arise due to centripetal force on the centre of mass and conservation of momentum (Newton's third law).

But any torque on the door will create a force on the hinges which is equal to $t/r$ or torque divided by radius. I'm looking both an intuitive and mathematically based explanation for this fact. I can sort of 'see' why, but my understanding is vague and uncertain.

Comment: It is very difficult to apply a _pure_ torque. What you are describing is a force at a distance which is where the reaction forces come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## My guess at what you're asking

I think I understand your question but I'm not 100% sure. Let me draw a picture.

The forces on a bar moving in a 2D plane about a center of rotation (black dot) look something like this:

[image: A thin black rectangle (the door) extends to the right of a black dot (the hinge) to its left. A red arrow comes down from its right hand side and is labeled "torquing force", a purple curve hovers over its right hand side curving around the edge pointing downward, labeled "angular velocity". On the left in blue, an arrow labeled "constraint force" near the hinge points down and to the left. Two tiny arrows, red and purple, are drawn alongside it into a triangle, to make it clear that the blue arrow is the vector-sum of these red and purple components: the red one parallel to the torquing force, the purple one pointing to the left.]

And that 2D bar is a model for a 3D door whose hinges are on a fixed axis.

Now the force of the door on the hinge is just the equal-and-opposite force demanded by Newton's third law to this "constraint force" in blue. So you are asking, why does this constraint force have as one of its components this "skinny red component" arrow that corresponds to the torquing force? And why is it pointing in this perhaps-surprising direction downward, and when does it instead point upward? These are great questions.

Note that if the door had no hinge, and you wanted to make it rotate around its *center* rather than its edge, you would pull "up" on the left hand side and push "down" on the right hand side, in the diagram above. So this little red component would actually point upwards to meet that constraint. But now when it's on the *edge* we have this problem that the center-of-mass can move, so there's nothing super-wrong with having the two forces both point in the same direction or opposite. It turns out that this will depend a lot on $r$, the radial length at which the torquing force is applied. Still speaking very crudely, if $r$ is very very far (perhaps even further than the door length $L$ if it has a massless prong inserted into it!) then you will find that the torque "rotates the door too much" to keep the hinge at the right place, and therefore the constraint force points in the same direction; but if $r$ is small then the torque "doesn't rotate the door enough" and the constraint force has to step in to help.

## Start with the constrained *motion*.

Well the key in doing this precisely is in the name I gave it, it is a "constraint force" and needs to be **whatever is necessary** to keep the hinge point from moving anywhere else in the plane. So what is necessary?

Well if the hinge is truly fixed then the door can be described in 2D purely by one angle, $\theta$, which the door makes at the hinge with the horizontal direction; the above diagram happens to show $\theta = 0.$ Now the center-of-mass of the door is at the position $[x, y] = \frac L2 [\cos\theta, \sin\theta].$ We sometimes invent two new perpendicular unit vectors, one called $\hat r = [\cos\theta, \sin\theta],$ and one called $\hat \theta = [-\sin\theta, \cos\theta].$ They are a little confusing! The normal unit vectors $\hat x = [1,0]$ and $\hat y = [0,1]$ are the same everywhere, these depend on what $\theta$ is! But they are very useful for just saying "the center of mass is at position $\hat r ~L/2$."

Anyway this expression gives us just what we need when we start taking time derivatives. The first time derivative is $$[v_x, v_y] = \frac L2 [-\sin\theta, \cos\theta] \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac L2 ~\omega~ \hat \theta,$$ where $\omega = d\theta/dt$ is the instantaneous angular velocity. So this is obvious, "the thing only moves in the $\theta$-direction perpendicular to the $r$-direction." The next time-derivative however needs to be done with the "product rule" and gives us,$$\begin{array}{rl}[a_x, a_y] =& \frac L2 [-\cos\theta, -\sin\theta] \left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2 + \frac L2 [-\sin\theta, \cos\theta] \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\\
=& -\frac L2 ~\omega^2~ \hat r + \frac L2 ~\alpha~\hat \theta\end{array}$$ where $\alpha = d\omega/dt$ is the angular acceleration. So these are the **only** ways the thing can accelerate, if the hinge is fixed. The first term is the centripetal force term that we know and love; the second term is due to the torques on the thing.

## Now derive the constraint force from that motion.

We now know the only way the thing is allowed by the "hinge has to stay at one place" constraint to accelerate, and we can see some interesting results.

So first off, as a no-brainer: if the torquing force $\vec T$ is not perfectly perpendicular to the door, we have to extract its normal component $T_\theta = \vec T \cdot \hat \theta$ to influence $\alpha$ and anything else is eaten by the hinges. If the force is provided at a distance $r$ from the hinge, its torque is therefore $\tau = T_\theta ~r$ and this produces an angular acceleration $\alpha = \tau/I = T_\theta~r/I,$ which I'll be plugging into the above expression in a moment.

The *constraint force* $\vec C$ of course comes to fill this gap between "what motions are possible?" and "what are the forces?". For example if you're standing on the ground, then the constraint says "You are not accelerating in the up/down direction" and therefore the normal force provides whatever force it needs to, to make these balance out: this is why the normal force equals your weight. (It is **not** because of Newton's third law; it is because you are in a state of up-down "equilibrium" which can only happen if the forces on you balance out.) Something similar is happening with this hinge.

So because we know from Newton's second law, the sum of these constraint and torquing forces $\vec C + \vec T$ must be equal to the mass times the acceleration, but I just told you the only possible acceleration:
$$ \vec C + \vec T = m \vec a = -m ~\frac L2 ~\omega^2~ \hat r + m~\frac L2 ~\frac{\tau}I~\hat \theta,$$ because we know the only way that this thing can accelerate, as per the above. Since $\vec T = T_r ~\hat r + T_\theta~ \hat \theta$ we can combine these $\hat \theta$ parts into saying,$$\vec C = -\left(m  ~\frac L2 ~\omega^2 + T_r\right)~ \hat r + T_\theta ~ \left(\frac {mLr}{2I} - 1\right)~\hat\theta.$$

So the component of the constraint force "parallel to the door," as you say, is equal to $-T_r$ plus the centripetal force due to its existing rotation. The component "perpendicular to the door" is more complicated; for this you need to know that $I = \frac13 m L^2$ and hence this is $(\frac32 r/L - 1)~T_\theta.$ That means that if you place the torquing force 2/3rds of the way out, it happens to rotate the door exactly as much as it pushes it in the direction it wants to go, leading to no constraint-force component; any further and it tries to "twist the door too much." So we don't even need the "massless prong" above; just pushing on the last third of the door will force the hinge to push in the same direction that we do.

Comment: surely we have to treat angular momentum separately from linear momentum? (just using magnitudes and perpendicular components), we know that the torque from $C$ and the torque from $T$ must add to give the resultant torque, $\frac{L}{2}^2\dot{\omega}$, so $C \cdot{ 0} + T \cdot{r} = \frac{L}{2}^2\dot{\omega}$ - the force from the hinges doesn't do anything to balance resultant torque on the door. We cannot divide by the general $r$ and equate forces, can we? Therefore the force at the hinges must be 0 due to the rotation of the door. The balancing must be done by some other torque on the door.

Comment: also, something i don't understand, if force is mr *dw/dt, then that implies that at a constant force at a larger radius produces less angular acceleration?

Comment: I'm starting to think that maybe there really isn't a 'tangential force'. If we liken the situation to two objects orbiting each other, with one firmly fixed in place, both planets should still be attracted to the centre of mass of the orbit, which is only in line with the masses

Comment: I am not sure about what exactly you are asking. Newton's laws say that for a bunch of particles indexed by $i$ obeying internal forces $U_{ij}=-U_{ji}$ and external forces $F_i$, that $m_i~\ddot r_i=F_i+\sum_jU_ij.$ We see that it would be nice to sum over $i$ and define $M=\sum_im_i,R=\sum_i(m_i/M) r_i$ to find $M~\ddot R=\sum_iF_i,$ the internal forces disappear in their momentum conservation and the external forces act on the center-of-mass. So if we can say "the center of mass moves this way and the external forces are $C$ and $T$" then that is one of our equations.

Comment: However the other of our equations indeed comes from the uniform rotation of the system about the point, which must indeed be governed by torques and angular accelerations in addition (you'll notice that nowhere above did I mention the concept of *rigidity* of the particles, it holds for any collection of particles). So that's where I was all like, "hey, we know $I=mL^2/3$ and $\tau = T_\theta~r$ so we have $\alpha=\ddot\theta=\tau/I=T_\theta~r/(mL^2/3).$

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see where you're going wrong. The force $C$ happens to be applied at the center of rotation of the door and therefore has zero torque. This does **not** mean that it is a zero force, just that it cannot torque the system about that point. It is still a valid force for when you're trying to figure out the motion of the center-of-mass.

Answer (score 0):

It is only due to the hinges that that when the door is pushed ,that it doesn't translate along the line of action of force applied and the hinges changes the velocity of the door and thus a force is necessary for that.This force is variable , changing its direction every instant

Answer (score 0):

An object can be in rotational non-equilibrium while simultaneously being in translational equilibrium depending upon the arrangement of the forces. In other words, an object can undergo an accelerating spin without translating. You can add rotational energy to an object without adding translational energy.

What I wrote above was meant as a hopefully helpful hint. I'll clarify below.

This is a very simple structural engineering problem. A hinge is a structural component that, by definition, can only have a resultant x-direction force and a resultant y-direction force.

You apply a force to the outer region of the door, setting up a torque acceleration of the door. You can mathematically slide the torque force to the hinge. That force now acts on the door at the hinge location. You've also mathematically noted the torque about the hinge as a circular arrow in the proper direction. The one reaction component at the door hinge exactly counters your applied force so that translation in that direction is impossible because the forces are balanced. The OTHER reaction at the hinge directly balances the centripetal acceleration of the rotationally accelerating door. It's much like whirling a ball on a string.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @rpfphysics I'll clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Pure torque does not produce any forces. So it is not true that "any torque on the door will create a force on the hinges".

Comment: It does though, of the magnitude stated

Comment: No. You can only have forces if the net force is otherwise nonzero. This is basic mechanics. In the case the OP is thinking about the torque is created by applying a force. If torque was created by a force pair with vanishing net force, then there would be no reaction force, obviously.

Comment: oh ok, but I was wondering specifically about situations like this door, before generalising it

Answer (score 0):

If you view the torque as Force * Radius * Sin(angle between force and door) then you can see that t/r is the component of force perpendicular to the door if that force were applied at radius r from the hinge. Now imagine the forces on the hinge if you wanted to generate the same torque at various radii.  The closer I push to the hinge, the more the hinge has to push back to get the door to rotate and the further out I push, the smaller the force, thus the 1/r relationship between the force on the hinge and the radius of the applied force.

Comment: my question was asking *why* there is a force on the hinge in the first place

Comment: Well, what happens if you push on the door at a radius between the center of mass of the door and the hinge? If the hinge were not there the door would want to rotate about it's own center of mass.  Because you are fixing the axis of rotation  there must then be a zero net force on the hinge, an applied force on the hinge and an equal and opposite force provided by the hinge.

Comment: Now that I've given this more thought, the applied force on the hinge will depend on where on the door I push relative to it's center of mass, but the net force on the hinge will still need to be zero.  If I push at a radius further than the CoM then the force applied to the hinge should be in the opposite direction of my push, and if I'm interior to the CoM it would be in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

"Any" torque will not create a force. Take the simple example of a force $F$ (and the **only** force in this problem) perpendicular to the door at a distance $r$ from the hinge. The torque's magnitude is $|\tau|=|rF|$ and there is **no** force on the hinge by the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a situation where a pinned object has a pure torque applied (no net force) that causes rotation and reaction forces on the hinges.

The intuition behind this scenario is that the net force on a body goes towards moving the center of mass. In this case, although no applied force exists, the net force is not zero because the center of mass orbits about the joint.

So the force is a result of the joint constraint and that the body is *forced* to rotate about an axis away from the center of mass.

Imagine the body is stationary to begin with. If the distance between the center of mass and the joint is $c$ then the reaction force $F_R$ causes the center of mass to move by $$ F_R = m a_{CM} = m c \ddot{\theta} $$

The applied torque $\tau$ as well as the torque due to the reaction causes the body to rotate $$ \tau - c F_R = I \ddot{\theta} $$

These two equations are solved for $$\begin{align} F_R & = \frac{m\, c \,\tau}{I+m c^2} \\ \ddot{\theta} &= \frac{\tau}{I+m c^2} \end{align} $$

So to answer your question *it is the motion of the center of mass* that causes the forces to arise at the hinges. The first equation above indicates the magnitude of this force depending not only on the applied torque $\tau$ but also the inertial properties of the body. Thus indicating this is a dynamic force.

Answer (score 0):

> But any torque on the door will create a force on the hinges which is equal to t/r or torque divided by radius.

Well, actually it is in fact *not* that torque that causes the force. The force on the hinges comes not because of the torque but because of the *motion*!

You almost explain it yourself here:

> If a door is rotated about its fixed axis in (outer) space, a force parallel to the door on the hinges will arise **due to centripetal force** on the centre of mass and conservation of momentum (Newton's third law).

What causes the centripetal force? Not some external force, but merely the fact that the particles of the door must start *turning*. When they are in motion (having a speed) they wish to stay on the straight track, but the hinge holds on to them and pulls them inwards to make them turn. This "turning" means acceleration, and Newton's 2nd law says that such acceleration is the result of a force - that force is at the hinge.

Answer (score 0):

> But any torque on the door will create a force on the hinges

This is not true.

There is no torque in principals of motion. In a nutshell, first law of Newton defines force and second law describes relation between force (defined by first law) and position vector of the particle. Third law is about action and reaction forces.

When two forces equal in magnitude $F$ but opposite in direction that act in a distance $r$ with respect to each other, we define **their** torque by $t=Fr$.

We should go in the right direction from principals (or laws) to definitions not vice versa. If we want to do inverse path, we should take into account the definitions or we must change our accepted principals. So, when there is a torque, certainly there have been two forces that have produced the torque according to its definition.

Torque doesn’t **create** any force. There is no torque at all. What exists according to the principals accepted by us, is force and if something should create another thing, it is force that create torque by getting help from another force.